# How do I compare numbers in a string array?

Tags: arrays, parsing

For example, the file I need to compare is something like this, all being separated by tab. I need to compare the times and scores of the 2 different people. The file looks something like this with the first number being a time in seconds and the second being a score.

John Smith 10 30
Peter Green 99 85

My code so far:

```
    File testResults= new File("TestResults.txt");
    Scanner inputFile= new Scanner(testResults);
    String[] testResultArr=new String[4];
    int c=0,minTime=0,minGrade=0,maxGrade=0,avgGrade=0,sum=0,time=0,scores=0;

    while(inputFile.hasNext()) 
    {
      String line= inputFile.nextLine(); 
      testResultArr= line.split("\t");
      time= Integer.parseInt(testResultArr[2]);
      scores= Integer.parseInt(testResultArr[3]);
      minTime=time;
      if(minTime<time)
        minTime=time;
    }     
    System.out.println("Lowest Time: "+minTime);
```

Output: 99
when it should have been 10.

Comment: Isn't your comparison backwards?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your code here:

```
minTime=time;
  if(minTime<time)
    minTime=time;
```

You are resetting the minimum time every iteration of the while loop. What you meant to do was declare minTime outside of the scope of the while loop (which you did), and then write:

```
if(time<minTime)
  minTime=time;
```

In this way, your minimum time is actually being saved.